# Hows does this macro work?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I wrote the following C code:

```
#define MAX_T(a,b,d) \
    { int len = (d);printf("len %d", len);}

int main()
{
    //MAX_T(10,30, smgarbage)
    MAX_T(10,30, len)
}
```

When I comment out `MAX_T(10,30, smgarbage)` and run it, it outputs **`len 24`**. When I comment out `MAX_T(10,30, len)` and run `MAX_T(10,30, smgarbage)` I get this compiler error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':  
test.c:34: error: 'smgarbage' undeclared (first use in this function)  
test.c:34: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once  
test.c:34: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

when executing `MAX_T(10,30, len)` why compiler error is not coming?
Is statement `int len = (d);` causing this? How?

Comment: but why its even compiling?

Comment: Because it's not a syntax error

Comment: If you ask the preprocessor (`gcc -E`, `cpp`, MSVC "keep preprocessed source" etc) nicely, it'll tell: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cef46891bcd627b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After macro substitution, `MAX_T(10,30, smgarbage)` will be:

```
{ int len = (smgarbage);printf("len %d", len);}
```

Apparently no delcaration of `smgarbage`.

`MAX_T(10,30, len)` will be:

```
{ int len = (len);printf("len %d", len);}
```

This will compile although the output is unknown since `len` contains garbage value.

It's the same as:

```
{
    int len;
    len = len;
    printf("len %d", len);
}
```